# How to update and insert multiple row in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array `$feedArray`something like this

```
Array ( [0] => array('id'=>'3','val=>'Renta Comerciales'),
        [1] => array('id'=>'4','val=>'Renta de Casas'),
        [2] => array('id'=>'6','val=>'Venta de Casas '),
        [3] => array('id'=>'7','val=>'Venta de Departamentos'), 
        [4] => array('id'=>'1','val=>'Venta de Terrenos') )
```

I have to make two query in a table called `categoriasPlantilla`

Then table has three columns

```
plantilla ,categoriaFeed, id
```

I have to check if the `val` of the array exist  in the `categoriafeed`  column of table then I have to update that id with the array id

if not then I have to insert a new row to the table

The value for plantilla is 11

I know how to do multiple insert in one query but how I can build such a query for update ?

To begin I was thinking of doing something like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO categoriaplantilla (plantilla,categoriafeed,id) values ";
    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE  categoriaplantilla ";
    foreach($feedArray as $key =>$val)
    {
        $sqlUpdate . =;
        $sql . = ;
    }
```

Please help me out

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't update rows set in one query. One row - one query. Also, you can use something like this

```
UPDATE table SET field1='aaa', field2='bbb' where id IN (1, 2,4).
```

But this query will set equal data to each row.
Sometimes I use this one

```
INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) VALUES ('aaa', 'bbb')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE SET field1='aaa', field2='bbb' where id IN (1, 2,4)
```

ps if you are use PK in your query, you may forgot about preformance almost in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions used are based on checking primary keys, like `INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY`, or `REPLACE INTO...`.

But, if you are checking non-primary keys which is column `categoriaFeed` as you mentioned, I suggest you can create a mysql procedure to do that using mysql functions.

The basic code should be like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS func;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE func()
BEGIN
    IF '123' in ('Renta Comerciales', 'Renta de Casas', 'Venta de Casas') THEN
        UPDATE `may` SET `fone` = 'aaaaa' WHERE `id` = 1;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO `may` VALUES ('1','2','3');
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL func();
```

The `123` equals to your `val`, you can check if it's in your given array. Then you can just update or insert data by the `if-statement`.

This is probably an useful way to solve your problem. I'm in `GMT+8` time zone and I'm gonna sleep now, it's 23:00PM. I'll check your replies tomorrow to see what I can help then.

Comment: what about using `Replace into` , I changed the columns, Plantilla and CategoriaFeed to primary key

Comment: `Replace into` is mostly liked `Insert into`, the only difference is that it will check if pk of the new record you insert exists in your old records. If so, the old one will be deleted, then new one will be inserted.